# How to make Zend Framework CLI work in Aptana Studio 3's terminal view?

Tags: zend-framework, aptana

I'm trying to make Zend's command line tool to work in Aptana's terminal view (on Windows), so I can use commands like "zf create model User" directly from aptana.

So far I've managed to get the zf command work by making an alias like this `alias zf=/path/to/zend/bin/zf.sh` but now I'm stuck because I have to make php's cli work too.. and I guess i can't do the same thing since I have a Windows version of php.

Is there a better way (adding zf to PATH?) to do this? A step by step tutorial would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check:

- http://blog.flashgen.com/php-development/adding-zend-tool-as-an-external-command-in-eclipse/
- http://blog.madarco.net/263/using-zend_tool-in-eclipse/